# How to downsample .json file

Tags: python, json, bigdata, data-science

I apologize if this is a very beginner-ish question. But I have a multivariate data set from reddit ( https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/submissions/), but the files are way too big. Is it possible to downsample one of these files down to 20% or less, and either save it as a new file (json or csv) or directly read it as a pandas dataframe? Any help will be very appreciated!

Here is my attempt thus far

```
def load_json_df(filename, num_bytes = -1):
    '''Load the first `num_bytes` of the filename as a json blob, convert each line into a row in a Pandas data frame.'''
    fs = open(filename, encoding='utf-8')
    df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(x) for x in fs.readlines(num_bytes)])
    fs.close()
    return df

january_df = load_json_df('RS_2019-01.json')

january_df.sample(frac=0.2)
```

However this gave me a memory error while trying to open it. Is there a way to downsample it without having to open the entire file?

Comment: The data seems to be compressed JSON Lines. You could decompress it with the system tool (e.g. `bzip2`) and pipe it into a python process which reads a line, makes a decision and if positive write the line to a file. Loading all file into memory would bring you into troubles.

Comment: Do accept an answer that solves your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, it is not possible to determine exactly what the 20% of the data is. In order to do that you must first read the entire length of the file and only then you can get an idea of what a 20% would look like.

Reading a large file into memory all at once throws this error generally. You can process this by reading the file line-by-line with below code:

```
data = []
counter = 0
with open('file') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
        counter +=1
```

You should then be able to do this

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in data]) #you can set a range here with counter/5 if you want to get 20%
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded first of the files, i.e. https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/submissions/RS_2011-01.bz2
decompressed it and looked at the contents. As it happens, it is not a proper JSON but rather JSON-lines - a series of JSON objects, one per line (see http://jsonlines.org/ ). This means you can just cut out as many lines as you want, using any tool you want (for example, a text editor). Or you can just process the file sequentially in your Python script, taking into account every fifth line, like this:

```
with open('RS_2019-01.json', 'r') as infile:
    for i, line in enumerate(infile):
        if i % 5 == 0: 
             j = json.loads(line)
             # process the data here
```